# cannot reference DATABASE_VERSION before supertype constructor has been called

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I wany to make CRUD from SQLite to My Android Studio i found the error like this : cannot reference DATABASE_VERSION before supertype constructor has been called. the error is signed by //The Error. Can you help Me please.

```
public class DataHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "biodatadiri.db";
    public final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    //The Error
         public DataHelper(Context context) {
             super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
         }  
    //The Error
```

Comment: make `DATABASE_VERSION` `static` or pass it as constructor parameter

Comment: Its Solve. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3):

Make the `DATABASE_VERSION` static.

ie, replace

```
public final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
```

with

```
public static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
```

Comment: Oh, there is already a similar answer from  @ρяσѕρєя K in comments.